# Does org.jetbrains.annotations.Contract can handle Integer range?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

My goal is to remove hard coded parameter check at runtime. From what I see, `@Contract` is just a Java annotation and it will not inject any logic at compile. In this case, `greater than` and `less than` parameter check.

My expected result: I can handle range with `@Contract`, so developer will be notified if they use the method outside the spec.

My actual result: intelliJ IDEA does not expect my contract.

What I've did:

1. I tried to use:

```
@Contract(_ < 1000 || _ > 4999,_ -> fail) // IntelliJ IDEA does not expect `_ < 1000 || _ 4999`

@Contract(number,_ -> fail) // IntelliJ IDEA does not expect `number` although in the documentation, it is a syntax.
```

Hard coded parameter check.

```
    /**
     * @param code in the range 1000-4999 except 1005, 1006, 1015
     * @param reason if reason != null, then code != null
     * @return unmasked-ws-frame
     */
    public byte[] encodeCloseFrame(Integer code, String reason) {
      if (code == null || code == 1005) {
        return null;
      }

      if (code == 1006 || code == 1015)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("/code/ " + code + " is a reserved value and MUST NOT be set as a status code in a Close control frame by an endpoint");

      if (code < 1000 || code > 4999)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("/code/ in the range 1000-4999");

      if (reason != null) {
      }

      return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `org.jetbrains.annotations.Range` annotation. And the description of the `Return value is outside of declared range` inspection provides some more useful information.